# How to remove page from the sitemap file generated by react-static?

Tags: reactjs, sitemap, react-router-dom, react-static

According to [documentation](https://github.com/nozzle/react-static/blob/master/docs/config.md), setting route property noindex to true like the example below it would prevent the page to be included in sitemap:

```
<Route component={privacyPolicyPage} path="/privacy-policy" noindex="true"/>
```

For the sake of completeness, here the relevant code for route map:

```
//app.js

import React from 'react'
import { Root } from 'react-static'
import { Route, Switch, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/p1" component={About} />  
    ...
    <Route component={About} path="/about" priority="0.1" />
    <Route component={PrivacyPolicy} PrivacyPolicy path="/privacy-policy" noindex="true" />
    <Route component={p404} noindex="true" />

</Switch>
```

Yet, neither it removes the privacy-policy url or even change any priority.

It is my first time with reactjs framework, so it is most likely i miss understood something.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that this prop is Boolean type, so please try this:

```
<Route component={privacyPolicyPage} path="/privacy-policy" noindex={true}/>
```

Using `noindex="true"` will pass a string value...